# How to fix trembling text with right-align?

Tags: javafx

I use Label on JavaFX8 with right-align to enter numbers one by one. The problem is that the text is trembling.

[image: gif example]

Application running on Ubuntu 18.04, JRE 1.8.0_211. Font used "Roboto Mono", but problem has with any font. I tried using TextField, but the situation is the same. Noticed that there are no problems with left align.

```java
public class AppExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ccffcc; -fx-font-weight:bold; -fx-font-size: 24pt");
        label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(label);
        vBox.setFillWidth(true);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 400, 100));
        primaryStage.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)) {
                int length = label.getText().isEmpty() ? 0 : label.getText().length()-1;
                label.setText(label.getText().substring(0, length));
            } else label.setText(label.getText() + event.getText());
        });
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I expect that the text should be entered without trembling, what are the possible solutions to the problem?